# what are the differences between SQL and Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

What are the main differences b/w SQL and HIve?

Its for the interview purpose

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL and HiveQL are programming language that helps to improve the design of the database. Some people tend to use them alternating but they are quite different.

### SQL & HiveQL

- Both can be used on structured data
- HiveQL support schema for data insertion while SQL support schema for data storage
- SQL is used when we need frequent modification in records whereas HiveQL to query large data sets and analyze historical data.
- SQL has hundreds of built-in functions while HiveQL has a limited number of built-in functions.
- SQL support updates, delete, and insert while HiveQL does not support any.

Comment: Its a very good answer but i feel like hive and SQL are two different topics and hiveQL is one part of hive. However, I am not sure whether OP wants to know difference between hvieQL and SQL so i assumed its hive.

Comment: Hive supports updates and deletes. "SQL" here doesn't mean anything without clarifying what database you're using with it. For example, SQL on Solr is different from SQL in Presto or SQL Server or Postgresql, etc

Answer (score 0):

**HIVE**
This is a tool by Apache built to query large distributed storages (mostly hadoop distributed file system) by using a SQL like language or statements. Its a tool to facilitate users who are familiar with SQL to work on HDFS. So, like any DB query tool it has few components like - query parser, query executor, coordinator, resource manager etc. to work properly.
You can get more info [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HIVE#Home-ApacheHive)

**SQL**
In comparison to hive, this is an umbrella term for querying information from a structured data. So, this is just a language like C, C++, Python with proper syntax/format/standards etc. and any developer can use this to access/modify any structured data. People can write long paragraph on this but you can read all about from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).